# Every natural number can be expressed uniquely as the sum of $k$ binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

for $N \in \mathbb N$ and $k \in \mathbb N$ prove that there exist unique $0\le x_1 \lt x_2\lt \dots \lt x_k$ such that
$$N = \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{x_i}{i}$$

edit: i've tried looking for combintorial proof but i couldnt find the right interpretation since $x$-es are not given.

then i tried looking at right pascal triangle and tried a few numbers, I found out that i always take the biggest possible
$x_k$ for $k$, then the biggest possible $x_{k-1}$ for $k-1$ sort of how you find binary expression for natural numbers.

Comment: What if N = 1 and 1 < k?

Comment: @WilliamElliot then $x_k=k$ and $x_i=i-1$ for all $i<k$. 
$$ \binom{0}{1}+ \binom{1}{2}+\ldots+\binom{k-2}{k-1}+\binom{k}{k}=0+0+\ldots+0+1$$

Comment: You are using an unusual definition of binomial coefficients requiring factorials of negative numbers. @ThomasLesgourgues

Comment: There are no negative numbers here. the initial definition of binomial number does not include factorial values, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Definition_and_interpretations
$$ \ $$
For natural numbers (taken to include $0$) $n$ and $k$, the binomial coefficient $\binom {n}{k}$ can be defined as the coefficient of the monomial $X^k$ in the expansion of $(1 + X)^n$.
$$\ $$
This is perfectly defined for $k>n$ and take a value of $0$. It's true that if $k\leq n$ you can compute the specific value using factorial form. But that's a specific case.